# How to see Next.js context in DevTools?

Tags: next.js

I try console.log() Next.js context from getServerSideProps function, but it's work only in terminal. This is very inconvenient and I see it in devTools but get various errors when I am affected or converted to JSON:

[image]

How i can see context in DevTools?

Answer (score 2):

The getServerSideProps function runs on the server side so it doesn't have access to browser.

Comment: And is there really no way to somehow pass this as props to the page?

Comment: It may be possible to just pass the res and req objects without converting them to strings as props to the same component. Then you can log whichever fields you want to console. Check these out: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse